# easteregg when string is written

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I am trying to implement a function on my website. The idea is to have some sort of Easter egg when the user writes letters in a defined order on his keyboard.

The user would have to write this directly on the website, not in a textarea or anything like this.

I thought using the jquery `.onkeypress` function but this function needs a selector and I'm not sure to be allowed to use that without an input.

Then I would need to store the key the user pressed in some string and reset the string if the user is pressing another key than the given string.

> 'qwerty' is the default string, if the user writes 'qwo' it resets the string

The code has to be as hidden as possible. Once the user writes the exact correct string, it would trigger something like an alert, but I know how to do this part. My problem is the javascript/jquery function.

Any help is appreciated, I've searched a lot on Google before asking but I don't even really know what to write to find something like this.

Thank you !

Comment: Add `.onkeypress` to the `$("body")` selector. Though expensive that's what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [progressive konami code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670787/progressive-konami-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just post my implementation as well, although the others were faster. :)
I prefer using the closure to keep the state hidden and simple string functions can easily solve this. So to change 'qwerty' to some other string, you just need to change the variable strTotype, aka this can be easily put into a constructor function.

```
window.addEventListener( 'keypress', (function() {
    var strToType = 'qwerty',
        strTyped = '';
    return function( event ) {
        var character = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
        strTyped += character;
        if (strToType.indexOf(strTyped) === -1) strTyped = '';
        else if (strTyped === strToType) {
            strTyped = '';
            alert('activate easteregg here');
        }
    };
}()) );
```

Comment: Fixed the reset logic.

Comment: Having the easter egg a little bit more hidden always is a nice thing :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I did something close to this, with jQuery.

I implemented the logic for "qwerty" already.

```js
let progress = 0;

$(window).bind('keydown', function(event) {
    let key = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
    switch (String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase()) {
        case 'q':
            progress += (progress == 0 ? 1 : 0);
            break;
        case 'w':
            progress += (progress == 1 ? 1 : 0);
            break;
        case 'e':
            progress += (progress == 2 ? 1 : 0);
            break;
        case 'r':
            progress += (progress == 3 ? 1 : 0);
            break;
        case 't':
            progress += (progress == 4 ? 1 : 0);
            break;
        case 'y':
            progress += (progress == 5 ? 1 : 0);
            if(progress == 6)
                printKeyToHtml("You did it");
            break;
        default:
            progress = 0;
            break;
            
    }
});

function printKeyToHtml(key) {
    $(".output").append(key);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">Get Easter, egged!</div>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, everything I need to have a good start ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider `window.addEventListener()` or `document.addEventListener()` (Vanilla Javascript)

Comment: whoops. typo. Will change

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using es6.

We are using the `matched` value to know what the current count of matched characters we have.

```js
const matchWord = (word, callback) => {
  let matched = 0
  const onKeyPress = e => {
    // convert the keycode to the character
    const char = String.fromCharCode(e.which)
    console.log(char)
    // check if the current character is the expected character
    if (word.charAt(matched) === char) {
      // move on to the next character
      matched++
    }
    else {
      // reset the counter
      matched = 0
    }
    if (matched === word.length) {
      callback(e, word)
      matched = 0
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('keypress', onKeyPress, true)
}

matchWord('qwerty', (e, word) => {
  console.log(`you typed ${word}`)
})
```